# How to git show the second last commit content on the current branch?

Tags: git

I use `git show` to see the content of the last commit on the current branch.  How do I git show the second last commit content? (ideally without having to know the 2nd last commit's hash).  Thanks!

Comment: `git show HEAD~1`, `git show HEAD~2`, `git show HEAD~3`. You get the idea.

Comment: [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git show` accepts any commit references as arguments: hashes, tags, branches etc. To refer to the second last commit, use `HEAD~` or `@~` (`~` means first the parent of the mentioned commit, `~2` is the first parent of the first parent etc)

```
git show @~
```